# Previously opened infoWindow gets focus when clicking clustered markers icon

Tags: google-maps, markerclusterer

I have an issue with my map.

Both markerClusterer and infoWindow work perfectly without any JS errors, but there is a strange behaviour.

- If I click a cluster icon, map zooms in and shows the markers and more clusters if needed **(OK)**.
- If I open a marker, and without closing it I click on a cluster icon, the map zooms in to the place, but suddenly the previously opened marker gets the focus **(not wanted)**.

**You can see this on link [1]**

I noticed that this happens only if "disableAutoPan" is set to false. If set it to true, it doesn't happen. **Example on link [2]**.

The problem is that I wanted this feature, so the infoWindow autofocus if it doesn't fit on the map view, but only when clicking on the marker, of course.

I tried adding some code to close any open infoWindows when clicking a cluster icon, but it doesn't work. It seems it works the first or second time, but then it stops working. **You can see this on link [3]**.

This is a fragment of the code to create one marker an its linked infoWindow:

```
                markerLocation = {
                    lat: 44.085821,
                    lng: -1.194248                }

                const infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: ""/*,
                    disableAutoPan: true*/
                });

                infoWindowArray.push(infowindow1);

                const marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: markerLocation,
                    map: map,
                    icon: "/alquileres-vacacionales/img/dk-marker.png"
                });

                marker1.addListener("click", () => {

                    if(openInfoWindow!=null) {

                        openInfoWindow.close();
                    }

                    openInfoWindow = infowindow1;

                    if(infowindow1.getContent()=="") {

                        fGenerateInfoWindowContent("FR3400.651.1", infowindow1);
                    }

                    infowindow1.open({
                        anchor: marker1,
                        map,
                        shouldFocus: false
                    });
                });

                markerCluster.push(marker1);
```

The following is the (very dirty) testing code I added to see if I could close previous infoWindows when clicking a cluster (only triggers when clicking the cluster image, which is 66px wide):

```
                $(document).on("click", "img[src='https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transparent.png']", function() {

                    if($(this).width()==66) {

                        for (var i = 0; i < infoWindowArray.length; i++ ) {
                            
                            infoWindowArray[i].close();
                        }

                        if(openInfoWindow!=null) {
                        
                            openInfoWindow.close();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I also added a listener in "map" to close the previously open infoWindow, which does what asked, but doesn't seem to help with my problem:

```
                google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {

                    openInfoWindow.close();
                });
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this "working as intended"? If so, any ideas how to make it work?

I checked the Google example page and it works fine, BUT I see thy have "disableAutoPan" set to "true":

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering

**LINKS:**

[1] https://staging.deskontaliaviajes.com/alquileres-vacacionales/stack.html

[2] https://staging.deskontaliaviajes.com/alquileres-vacacionales/stack-true.html

[3] https://staging.deskontaliaviajes.com/alquileres-vacacionales/stack-force-close.html

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue **in the question itself**, preferably a working [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers), not (just) links to external resources.

Comment: Hi geocodezip. I've been trying, but I'm not able of making a simple snippet work.
It's just a basic hello world html5 that loads the Google Maps library, and I get "script error" on the "new google.maps.Map..." instruction. I'll keep trying....

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] in jsfiddle that works and demonstrates your issue (from one of the Google examples)? It is pretty simple to translate a jsfiddle to a [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers), and there are Google test keys available that will allow the StackSnippet to display a map.

Comment: I have this happening too. Here is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75552315/prevent-markerclusterer-click-from-zooming-into-opened-infowindow

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it somehow.

**TL;DR**: I just switchet back to an older version of markerCluster library.

Checking some JSFiddle I found one where it didn't happen what I was experiencing (author: "/colas"):

```js
function initMap() {
         var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: 46.613317, lng: 2.349830},
            zoom: 9
         });
setMarkers(map);
      }

var points = [
    ['Point 1', 'adresse 1 ', 46.613317, 2.249830],
    ['Point 2', 'adresse 2 ', 46.713317, 2.249830],
    ['Point 3', 'adresse 3 ', 46.613317, 2.349830],
    ['Point 4', 'adresse 4 ', 46.713317, 2.449830],
    ['Point 5', 'adresse 5 ', 46.613317, 2.449830],
    ['Point 1', 'adresse 1 ', 46.413317, 2.249830],
    ['Point 2', 'adresse 2 ', 46.513317, 2.249830],
    ['Point 3', 'adresse 3 ', 46.513317, 2.349830],
    ['Point 4', 'adresse 4 ', 46.413317, 2.449830],
    ['Point 5', 'adresse 5 ', 46.513317, 2.449830],
];
var markersC = [];
function setMarkers(map) {
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        var point = points[i];
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                                position: {lat: point[2], lng: point[3]},
                                                map: map,
                                                title: point[0],
                                            });
markersC.push(marker);
        var contentString = '<div class="marker-infowindow">' +
                            '<h2>'+point[0]+'</h1>'+
                            '<div><a target="_blank" href="https://tutoandco.colas-delmas.fr/developpement/inserer-carte-google-maps-wordpress/?utm_source=jsfiddle&utm_medium=website">Voir le tuto complet</a></div></div>';


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i, contentString) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i, contentString));
    }
  
  // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
 var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markersC,
      {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
 <!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

First I rewrote my code following that example, BUT still had the same result.

Then I realized that the marketClusterer library used on this example was an older one (I was still using the latest "unpkg").

I downloaded an older library, and now my map is working correctly. The infoWindow adjusts to be visible on the map window when clicked, and the map doesn't move around back to it when I click a marker cluster.

**So basically, I changed this:**

```
const clusterObject = new MarkerClusterer(map, markersCluster, {
   imagePath: 'https://staging.deskontaliaviajes.com/alquileres-vacacionales/img/mc',
   maxZoom: 15
});
```

**To this:**

```
const clusterObject = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({
    map: map,
    markers: markersCluster
});
```

**And instead of using:**

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@googlemaps/markerclusterer/dist/index.min.js"></script>
```

**I used this:**

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer@gh-pages/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
```

The rest of the code is exactly the same (creation of map, markers, cluster, infowindow openings, etc...) but switching those fixed the issue.

In case it helps someone with a similar issue, here's the static working version:

https://staging.deskontaliaviajes.com/alquileres-vacacionales/stack-ok.html

Comment: I've removed the API key from the post for security and privacy concerns. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by closing the current infowindow when clicking on the cluster.

```js
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  disableAutoPan: false // keep the desired auto-pan
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.close(); // close the info window if the map is clicked.
});

var markers = add_markers(map, infowindow, coord_tables);

var mc = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({ map, markers });

google.maps.event.addListener(mc, 'click', function(cluster){
  infowindow.close(); // close the info window if a cluster is clicked.
});
```

With this, you can use the latest source:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@googlemaps/markerclusterer/dist/index.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue; I'm on markerclusterer 2.5.3

I noticed the issue happens when InfoWindow disableAutoPan option is enabled (default), so my workaround is to only enable that option before calling infoWindow.open() and set it back to disable right after. This way the info window stays open if user roams to another cluster and decides to go back to the previous marker.

```
marker.addListener("click", () => {
  //...

  infoWindow.setOptions({disableAutoPan: false});
  infoWindow.open({map: this.map, anchor: marker});
  infoWindow.setOptions({disableAutoPan: true});  

  //...
});
```